# parse a result from AJAX request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I have this ajax request:

```
var rootURL = "http://localhost/myapp/api/api.php";
$.ajax({
     type: 'GET',
     url: rootURL + '/favourites',
     dataType: "json", 
     success: function(list) {

     },
     error: function(list) {

     }
});
```

and the api.php makes a query to DB and the encoded result

```
echo '{"result": ' . json_encode($result) . '}';
```

is like this:

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "ID": "1",
            "username": "username1",
            "name": "name1",
            "year": "year1"
        },
        {
            "ID": "2",
            "username": "username2",
            "name": "name2",
            "year": "year2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now how can I get and print the two rows of the JSON result `list` in `success` callback in Javascript?
I tried this:

```
var decoded = JSON.parse( lista );
```

but I receive an error:  `JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`

Thanks

Comment: put the results into an attribute result ? Why not `echo json_encode($result);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You dont't need to parse, just you need to iterate the array inside the **result**.

do like this:

```
success: function(list) {

    $.each(list.result,function(index,item){

    console.log(item);

    });
}
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cDq2z/)

Comment: @BastienSander No! Here one have to loop in it because `result` holds an array which contains some js objects in it.

Comment: There only one instance of list.result, so I don't get the reason of $.each

Comment: What will you do to take something from list.result. $.each is for iterating through each item in list.result

Answer (score 2):

Don't call `JSON.parse`. jQuery does that for you when you say `dataType: "json"`. `list` is an object. So just access `list.result`, which contains the result array.

Also, your PHP shouldn't build the JSON by hand like that. It should do:

```
echo json_encode(array('result' => $result));
```

Comment: thanks, very helpful to remind me I forgot: "jQuery does that for you when you say dataType: 'json'". :)